# Import certificate to Trusted Root Authorities for the Current User, with command line

Tags: windows, certificate, trusted-root-certificates, certutil, trusted-root-ca

I know how to import certificates to trusted root authorities with certutil

```
certutil -addstore "Root" <cert_path>
```

But for this I need administrator permissions. Though when I double click on the certificate to install it with the GUI, I get the option to install it only for the current user, in which case I don't need admin. permissions.

[image]
[image]

Therefore my questions is: **How to import with command line a certificate to Trusted Root Authorities with no administration rights**?

Comment: Are you running an elevated command prompt?

Comment: @spikey_richie actually, no, I have no admin rights on this machine

Answer (score 4):

It was so simply I couldn't imagine

```
certutil -user -addstore "Root" <cert_path>
```